# How to dump contents from print statement in python into excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a python file that looks through a .txt file and searches for the specific elements I need in that file and prints these element in rows separated by commas, each row for a different replicate. This code works as expected.

Now that I see it works via print, instead of printing I want to automatically put these elements into an excel file. I am at this point, and am getting the following error:

"OS Error: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '/home/ubuntu/Desktop'"

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path


desktop = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/test.xlsx")
word = "HbA1c"
percent = "%"
indicator = "TD"


with open("data.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if indicator in line:
                row = line.split("|")
                x = row[3]
                y = row[5]
        if percent in line:
            row = line.split("|")
            z = (row[3])
            #print(x.replace(" ", ""), y, z) #confirm it works

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'SID': [x],
    'Engine': [y],
    'Result': [z]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(desktop, engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

I've also tried the following (commenting out where I defined desktop at the top of the code) and it gives the same error. pythonfiles does indeed exist in my documents folder.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'Documents/pythonfiles/test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
```

I am using python via codespaces on github if that matters.

Comment: So, you are running this on a server computer, and not on your own machine?  It shouldn't be a surprise that you can't create arbitrary files.  It doesn't have access to your disk.  Since `data.txt` works, there must be some kind of a local file store.  Just put your xlsx there, and you'll need to figure out how to fetch it.

Comment: I actually wasn't able to import data.txt from my computer either. I named a window in python 'data.txt' and copied my data there

Comment: I don't know codespaces, but there must be a way for you to add files to your project other than your source code.  You just need to bear in mind that your program is not running on  your computer.  It's running on a computer far away, which does not have access to your disk.  If it needs files, you need to take steps to copy the files to that server.